# Force Declaring Array with specific sort of complex types

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need a way to declare array with a specific order of types to force setting the required properties of each type as

```
list: (Teacher , School , Student , Teacher)[] = [
{id:1,fName:'jo1',sName:'jo11',position:'first teacher'},
{id:1,name:'oxford',location'us'},
{id:1,name:'rob',level:'junior'},
{id:2,name:'gen',level:'Senior'},
{id:2,fName:'jo1',sName:'jo11',name:'jo222',position:'second teacher'}
]
```

```
interface Teacher{
id;
fName;
sName;
position;
} 

interface School{
id;
name;
location;
}

interface Student {
id;
name;
level;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `list` as a `tuple` not an array type:

```js
interface Teacher {
    id: number;
    fName: string;
    sName: string;
    position: string;
}

interface School {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    location: string;
}

interface Student {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    level: string;
}

let list: [Teacher, School, Student, Teacher] = [
    { id: 1, fName: 'jo1', sName: 'jo11', position: 'first teacher' },
    { id: 1, name: 'oxford', location'us'},
    { id: 1, name: 'rob', level: 'junior' },
    { id: 2, name: 'gen', level: 'Senior' },
    { id: 2, fName: 'jo1', sName: 'jo11', name: 'jo222', position: 'second teacher' }
]
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoUQC2sg3gKGSOWABMAuZEAVwFsAjaAbkOJgDk5aJKBnMKKADmLYsl6dufAcNHEADgHtewMMEUhpgkCPwBffPlCRYiFAGUEmRYoA2eVkTKUaDZo6pce4mTrlFbRQQ4NQ0tWX1DY2h4JGRzMGpSCHAHMWcqOkYof08pH21dMVsIADcIW3C-SPwSsGRbYH5KAG10LGgAGnirG1tuhKSUsG72q2gAXWQAXmQWj1wSCmQARm6OL0oAcgArRRWt7olN5F39g%206lFVDNU5hgKH5kSA6oLeQ9ToWlyjW87y2igAHjBFFBSIcGkEQuoQFtqLwtp9vhk-iATlsoIp6JCSuVKqcdtQQOo3h8vmJFhkAEzddH5LZCFK4soVbbmFKk97Iyk-ZC05AbBl7C7iSQAkWi%20kSxTUuWQq6qWHbXgQBAaUjPDDjMkGCZAA)